# Ubuntu USB Instalation problem

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I have a problem installing Ubuntu using a USB drive with Windows already installed. So i used the program Unetbootin and it booted up perfectly asked me if i want to try Ubuntu or installing.

I have tried both of them with the same result, it asks me the language, if i want to install updates and install 3rd party software and i say yes. After that it asks to restart the computer to install Ubuntu alongside Windows.

So, the computer restarts and the Ubuntu screen asks to remove installation media and press enter. I do so, but it does not install Ubuntu it just boots up Windows 7.

And inside Windows it does not prompt up a installation screen or nothing. I do not really know what i am doing wrong.

Thanks for the help and sorry if this was already asked.

Answer (score 0):

Better use Ubuntu 15.10. 
I guess your Problem is that you choose the wrong place for installing the bootloader.
Probably /dev/sda is the right one. NOT /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2... 
See here:
http://www.dedoimedo.com/images/computers_years/2014_1/ubuntu-install-bootloader.jpg